# COLUMNSTORE INDEX - can it help on my query if I add a filter? (MS SQL)

Tags: sql-server, indexing, columnstore

I am trying to optimize a query that uses a count(*) which cause a full index scan.

I have read about the columnstore indexes and think that can maybe help optimize the query.

However, I wonder if I should add a filter to make it even better?

The query I try to improve is this one:

```
SELECT status, count(*) num FROM HKT_TABLE WHERE oen_user=export_user GROUP BY status
```

The Index I was trying to create was this one:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX [HKT_INDEX] ON [dbo].[HKT_TABLE]
(
    [export_user],
    [oen_user],
    [status]
)WITH (DROP_EXISTING = OFF, COMPRESSION_DELAY = 0)
```

However, creating that index, did not help on the query, it only made it more slow.

So my idea was to try this index with a filter:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX [HKT_INDEX] ON [dbo].[HKT_TABLE]
(
    [export_user],
    [oen_user],
    [status]
) WHERE (oen_user=export_user)
```

But I am unable to create it, as the where clause is incorrect.

Any help on what I am missing or doing wrong? (I do not have the option to change the query, so can only create indexes or similar).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot create a filtered index predicate which compares two columns. If you look at [the grammar for it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-columnstore-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#syntax), you will see it only allows constants as the right side.

Instead you can create an indexed view, and then create a clustered columnstore index on that

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.HKT_filtered
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
    hkt.SomePrimaryKey,
    hkt.export_user,
    hkt.oen_user,
    hkt.status
FROM dbo.HKT_TABLE hkt
WHERE hkt.oen_user = hkt.export_user;
```

```sql
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CX ON dbo.HKT_filtered
    (SomePrimaryKey);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX HKT_INDEX ON dbo.HKT_filtered
    (export_user, oen_user, status);
```

On Enterprise Edition the compiler will automatically use it even with your existing query. However, even on this edition, it is better to query the view directly and [use the `NOEXPAND` hint](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/12/sql-performance/noexpand-hints).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I really appreciate your quick help! You made my day. :)